# Unable to use local temp table inside SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have a requirement, where I need to create a local temp table inside a SSIS package and populate and later use it in data flow. For that I have started with a POC , where I created the temp table inside execute sql task and populate it, later use the values present in temp table and populate the physical table. I followed the net and set retain same connection true , work offline and all. But I am able to do it only for global temp table , when I put local temp table instead , I get an error at oledb source saying that #ABC.. tmp file could not be found.Any suggestions , why it is not working for local tables.

Comment: Is the temp table created by the same connection that raises the error?

Comment: Yes , i am using only one connection in the package, that points to db,where local temp table needs to be created and the physical table is there.I t is working fine for global temp table but fails when i use local temp table.

Comment: When you say you "followed the net", can you post the link to the article you followed?

Comment: you can set data flow delayed validation ="True" .. it will work in this case

Comment: If there isn't too much data and it doesn't need to be indexed then you could store to a local SSIS variable instead. Here's how you write to one: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/cc879316(v=sql.105).aspx; here's how you read back out: http://www.timmitchell.net/post/2015/04/20/using-the-ssis-object-variable-as-a-data-flow-source/. Can you explain further why you need to store an intermediate recordset? There's probably another method to do it

Comment: the local temp table is recognized in another execute sql task, outside of which it is created. But when I use it in DataFlow task as source, it is not recognized. I want to know why this is happening.
and
@Tab Alleman, I followed http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2013/temp-tables-ssis/

Answer (score 0):

you can set the Data flow task propriety delay validation ='True'

Answer (score 0):

On your DB Connection Manager go to Properties, there is a setting "RetainSameConnection" Change that to True.

Comment: Thanks Inus C ,I have done that..The only thing I want to know when I create local temp table on another database it works throughout package , but when I create it on the same connection(database) , it fails inside the DFT , I want to know why this happens

Comment: I do not know why, maybe the first connection is still open, but a new connection is created when trying to reference the temp table. Something to try might be to use a ##TempTable and not #TempTable. if that is what you have. If what I said is true(not sure if it is) then it should work. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: It is working with ##TempTable , but the problem is when I use #TempTable the table is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

set MARS Connection property in connection manager to TRUE